# How to use Order Custom Field value in Email Template?

Tags: shopware

I want to use a custom field's value of order in Order Confirmation Mail. Are custom fields assigned to order template? And how can you assign variables other then order's to the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have access to the order's custom fields in mail template by `order.customFields['technical_name_of_custom_field']`. Put real technical name of your custom field instead of `technical_name_of_custom_field`.

In the email template by default you have access to following associations of Order

```
$criteria
        ->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingMethod')
        ->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.country')
        ->addAssociation('transactions.paymentMethod')
        ->addAssociation('lineItems')
        ->addAssociation('currency')
        ->addAssociation('addresses.country');
```

and orderCustomer as well.

Comment: Does that mean that the custom fields are not available in the order template? If yes then how can they be added? Through a subscriber or through overriding the default controller?

Comment: what do you mean exactly, custom fields definition or values of a custom field for current order? Values are available as i wrote at the beginning of my answer.